# Why is addition not commutative under PM's notion of relation number?

Tags: noncommutative-algebra, vector-space-isomorphism, congruence-relations

Quoting Bertrand Russell's "[The Principles of Mathematics](https://philarchive.org/archive/RUSTPO-77)" p468 §299:

> 299. It is worth while to repeat the definitions of general notions involved in terms of what may be called relation-arithmetic*. If P, Q
>      be two relations such that there is a one-one relation S whose domain
>      is the field of P and which is such that Q = (˘S)PS, then P and Q are
>      said to be like. The class of relations like P, which I denote by λP,
>      is called P’s relation-number. If the fields of P and Q have no common
>      terms, P **+** Q is defined to be P **or** Q or the relation which holds between
>      any term of the field of P and any term of the field of Q, and between
>      no other terms. Thus **P+Q is not equal to Q+P**. Again λP+λQ is defined
>      as λ(P + Q).
>      *Cf. Part IV, Chap. xxix, §231.

Where Principia Mathematica [symbols](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/pm-notation/) and [terminology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_Principia_Mathematica) use:

- the symbol ˘ to denote the converse relation.
- the word "field" to denote the union between the domain and co-domain of the relation.

First, a point of confusion is the tendency to assume binary relations in calling out  "domain" and "co-domain".  Is it not the case that n-place relations may have up to n distinct "domains", each of which supplies a value for a given place in a particular relationship of the relation's extension?

Second, as Russell specifies the two (n-ary) relations have "no terms in common" between their fields (as n-way unions of their respective n-domains), it seems the only compositional intension would be the disjunction (***or***) of their respective extensions. To bring this down to simple relation-tables:  One takes the rows of P and the rows of Q and puts them in the same relation table, regardless of row-order.  This is what one would expect of the + operator's logical analogue of ***or*** which, also, is commutative.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense that addition between relations is not commutative.
Take this easy example:
let P be the series of natural number in order of magnitude and let Q the ordered couple (-1;-2).
Then the series P+Q is just the series that you get if, metaphorically, you "put" the couple Q at the "end" of P; while Q+P is just the series that you get by putting Q at the beginning of P.
The first series P+Q is a well ordered series but is not a progression (i.e: is not isomorphic to the series of natural number in order of magnitude; that term is used in Principia Mathematica *263); the second one, i.e, Q+P, is still a progression.

When P and Q are well ordered finite series, then it's true that P+Q=Q+P; but that result isn't true in general.

Answer (score 0):

Re: (1), I question whether relations in this context are $n$-ary or specifically binary - your question suggests the former, but relation algebra is usually set up for the latter (and I don't know how to make sense of the converse of a more-than-$2$-ary relation).

Re: (2), I believe the key point is the clause

> "or the relation which holds between any term of the field of P and any term of the field of Q

which distinguishes $P+Q$ from the mere union of $P$ and $Q$ (which is indeed commutative) - the idea is that if $p$ is in the field of $P$ and $q$ is in the field of $Q$, then $(p,q)\in P+Q$ but $(q,p)\not\in P+Q$ and conversely $(q,p)\in Q+P$ but $(p,q)\not\in Q+P$.

Comment: You must be correct that the context presumes binary P and binary Q but I don't understand the justification for assuming 2 place relations for relational algebra.  Moreover, this is relational arithmetic where the binary operation + is a binary function (binary N:1 relation -- the elements of whose field are relations).  As for making sense of "converse", that concept occurs only with regards to the "one-to-one" relation S  in the expression that defines 'like' relations P and Q:  Q = (˘S)PS